# Two questions about HTML5 web coding to Android device

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, sencha-touch, android-webview

**1**

Which one method is faster to open and use HTML5/jQuery Mobile page in android device?

Use Phonegap or just make normal activity with WebView? Page is in assets folder and App doesn't need to use any hardware component. It's just list of different web page links. And Every link should open second activity and open the link in WebView.

---

**2**

Someone says that Sencha Touch is faster than jQuery Mobile and someone else says that jQuery is as fast but much more stronger because there is more abilities to do. So which one is more recommended. Or is it only what you like is better? (Like it really doesn't matter which one you use)

jQuery is much more easier to start if you don't have experience about web coding. Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which one method is faster to open and use HTML5/jQuery Mobile page in android device?
>   Use Phonegap or just make normal activity with WebView? Page is in assets folder and App doesn't need to use any hardware component. It's just list of different web page links. And Every link should open second activity and open the link in WebView.

Normal Activity with Webview will be faster then using phonegap because phonegap takes more time to get the document to be ready as compared to Native thing.

> Someone says that Sencha Touch is faster than jQuery Mobile and someone else says that jQuery is as fast but much more stronger because there is more abilities to do. So which one is more recommended. Or is it only what you like is better? (Like it really doesn't matter which one you use)
>   jQuery is much more easier to start if you don't have experience about web coding. Am I right?

Yes you are right Jquery is much more easir then sencha touch. I use jquery mobile and its awesome. Although Sencha is little bit faster but i will recommend you to use Jquery mobile. :)

Answer (score 1):

In general yes JQM is a lot easier to learn. I've spent about a week now looking through Sencha and if you don't know EXT.js it seems pretty complex. Even the demos are confusing and it seems to be way more programmer oriented in the way things are constructed versus design oriented.

I'm also looking at netbiscuits tactile - but I haven't spent enough time looking at that yet.